# How do we know if there's a rotation matrix between two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

When does there exist a rotation matrix between two vectors? Clearly they must have the same length, but is that a sufficient condition?

Comment: What do you mean by "a rotation matrix between two vectors"? And what must have the same determinant?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this.  A vector in 3-space doesn't **have** a "determinant" so that may not be what   If two vectors have the same length then there exist a rotation that maps one into the other so a rotation matrix.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I messed up writing determinant, I meant magnitude.

Comment: Assuming you mean the vectors have the same length (instead of same determinant), the answer is yes. Every linear transformation can be represented as a matrix, and rotation by a given angle is a linear transformation.

Comment: So is it the case that two vectors v and w have a rotation matrix a mapping v to w iff v and w have the same magnitude?

Comment: How would you go about proving this?

Comment: The main ideas: check that rotations are linear indeed. Now look at the images of the basis vectors $(1,0,0...,0)^T, (0,1,0,...,0)^T,...,(0,0,0,...,1)^T$ by the rotation with the given angle. The matrix that has the images of these as columns, takes $(1,0,0...,0)^T, (0,1,0,...,0)^T,...,(0,0,0,...,1)^T$ into their image by the rotation with the given angle. (Just multiply the matrix with these basis vectors - the zeros and the one make sure, that the result is the $j$th column of the matrix when you multiply with the $j$th basis vector).

Comment: What definition of "rotation" are you using?  Different conventions exist for what "rotation" means in 3D or higher-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Thank you everyone! And how would you prove that there is no rotation matrix if the vectors do not have the same length?